# Mongoose Routing Specific Query Output

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mongoose newb question. I'm trying to build a MEAN application that queries an existing db based on user entered parameters. The database is being populated with JSONs by an outside program.

So far, I have my router successfully showing all of the Mongo records when I use the below router:

```
// Pulls all JSONs
router.get('/jsons', function(req, res, next) {
    Json.find(function(err, jsons){
        if(err) { return next(err);}

        res.json(jsons);
    });
});
```

Now I am trying to create a separate route which can show a specific field within that database. (Where TestLocation = "New York")

```
// Pulls a JSON with City New York
router.get('/jsons/NewYork', function(req, res, next) {
    var queryNYC = Json.where({TestLocation: "New York"});
    queryNYC.findOne(function(err, jsons) {
        if(err) { return next(err);}
        res.json(jsons);
    });
});
```

This is returning null to me, though the original route shows that one JSON record does indeed have a TestLocation of New York.

My schema looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Base schema for the query results table
var JsonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        uploadID: String,
        uploadDate: Date,
        testDate: Date,
        username: String,
        type: String,
        markers: String,
        image: String,
        TestLocation: String
    },
    {
        collection: 'data'
    }
);

mongoose.model('Json', JsonSchema);
```

So my question:

A) Am I setting this up correctly

B) Do I need my Mongoose schema to match what's in the DB exactly? My Mongoose schema has a field TestLocation which matches a TestLocation field in the MongoDB database, but I also have a lot of fields in the MongoDB database that aren't included in the schema. Do I need to include these to see this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing looks fine, the data in your database does not have to be the same as your data. Use the following:

```
Json.findOne({TestLocation: "New York"}, function(err, jsons) {
    if(err) { return next(err);}
    res.json(jsons);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer about the data mismatch being okay. Unfortunately, changing to findOne didn't yet solve my problem. Need to keep looking around.

Comment: Actually it looks like I found my own issue. The variable I was querying for was actually a parameter inside of a larger object.